# Function `dist` not behaving as expected on vectors with missing values

Tags: r

EDIT: I think, from my discussion below with @joran , that @joran helped me figure out *how* `dist` is altering the distance value (it appears to be scaling the sum of the squares of the coordinates by the value [total dimensions]/[non-missing dimensions], but that is just a guess).  What I'd like to know, if anyone does know, are: is that what is really going on?  If so, why is that considered a reasonable thing to do?  Can there, or should there be options to `dist` to compute it the way I proposed (that question might be to vague or of an opinionated nature to answer, though).

I was wondering how the `dist` function actually works on vectors that have missing values.  Below is a recreated example.  I use the `dist` function and a more fundamental implementation of what I believe should be the definition of Euclidian distance with sqrt, sum, and powers.  I also expected that if a component of either vector was `NA`, that that dimension would just be thrown out of the sum, which is how I implemented it.  But you can see that that definition doesn't agree with `dist`.

I will be using my basic implementation to handle the `NA` values, but I was wondering how `dist` is actually arriving at a value when vectors have `NA`, and why it doesn't agree with how I calculate it below.  I would think that my basic implementation should be the default/common one, and I can't figure out what alternate method `dist` is using to get what it is getting.

Thanks,
Matt

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1)
v2 <- c(1,2,3)
v3 <- c(1,NA,3)

# Agree on vectors with non-missing components
# --------------------------------------------
dist(rbind(v1, v2))
#          v1
# v2 2.236068

sqrt(sum((v1 - v2)^2, na.rm=TRUE))
# [1] 2.236068



# But they don't agree when there is a missing component
# Under what logic does sqrt(6) make sense as the answer for dist?
# --------------------------------------------
dist(rbind(v1, v3))
#         v1
# v3 2.44949

sqrt(sum((v1 - v3)^2, na.rm=TRUE))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Read the Details section of the documentation carefully. It's in there.

Comment: I did, here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/dist.html .  This was the key that didn't make sense: "Missing values are allowed, and are excluded from all computations involving the rows within which they occur."  I thought that meant it behaved as I thought.  Saw also: "If some columns are excluded in calculating a Euclidean, Manhattan, Canberra or Minkowski distance, the sum is scaled up proportionally to the number of columns used."  I don't know how the sum would be scaled up proportionally to get me sqrt(6) as the answer.

Comment: Maybe the sum of the squared diffs are scaled up from 4 to 6.

Comment: Yeah, and the only thing I can map to is that the scaling factor is "total dimensions / non-missing dimensions" which is 3/2, which would scale up the argument of sqrt(4) up to sqrt(6).  I'm not sure why that is a reasonable thing to do  (using that as your scaling factor) rather than just removing the dimensions that have NA in them from the sum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the scaling happens exactly like you described. Maybe this is a better example:

```
set.seed(123)
v1 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 100, TRUE)
v2 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), 100, TRUE)

dist(rbind(v1, v2))
#          v1
# v2 12.24745

na.idx <- is.na(v1) | is.na(v2) 
v1a  <- v1[!na.idx]
v2a  <- v2[!na.idx]

sqrt(sum((v1a - v2a)^2) * length(v1) / length(v1a))
# [1] 12.24745
```

The scaling makes sense to me. All things being equal, the distance increases as the number of dimensions increases. If somewhere you have a `NA` for dimension `i`, a reasonable guess for the contribution of dimension `i` to the squared sum is the mean contribution of all other dimensions. Hence the linear up-scaling.

While you are suggesting that when you find a `NA` for dimension `i`, that dimension should not contribute to the squared sum. It is like assuming that `v1[i] == v2[i]` which is totally different.

To summarize `dist` is doing some type of maximum-likelihood estimation, while your suggestion is more like a worst (or best) case scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the missing dimension adding the average amount from the non-missing dimensions.   That makes sense.

Comment: For the record, after thinking, both distance definitions will work for me.  I am looking to take a test point and determine to which point in a set of points the test point is closest to.  In that scheme, either way of computing distance is acceptable, as what I just need to do is find the pair with the smallest distance.  Both computations will lead me to pick the same pair.