# Does a function like dist/rdist exist which handles NAs?

Tags: r, package, distance, na

I'm using `rdist` function from `fields` package, but now I want to handle NAs in my matrix, like the `dist` function does.

There exist such a function?

One solution would be to use `dist` directly, but my matrix has over 150K rows, so this is not an option.

**Edit:**
Note than removing rows or columns with `complete.cases` or `na.omit` is not the solution I'm looking for. The intended behaviour is described in the help `dist` function:

*Missing values are allowed, and are excluded from all computations involving the rows within which they occur. Further, when Inf values are involved, all pairs of values are excluded when their contribution to the distance gave NaN or NA. If some columns are excluded in calculating a Euclidean, Manhattan, Canberra or Minkowski distance, the sum is scaled up proportionally to the number of columns used. If all pairs are excluded when calculating a particular distance, the value is NA.*

I add a sample code to ilustrate this. Given this vectors:

```
vx <- matrix(c(1,2,3), nrow=1)
vy <- matrix(c(2,7,10), nrow=1)
vy.na <- matrix(c(2,NA,10), nrow=1)
```

`dist` calculates the distance ignoring the 2nd column and scaling up to a 3 columns, so

```
dist(rbind(vx,vy))
dist(rbind(vx,vy.na))
rdist(vx,vy)
```

all return the same => 8.660254

but

```
rdist(vx,na.omit(vy.na))
```

Does not return any distance value because `na.omit` omits the whole row.

On the other hand calcuating the distances by pairs of vectors individually is a way slower than `rdist`.

My alternate solution is to fill NA with a 'neutral' value (like the median of that column) but I would prefer the `dist` behaviour.

Comment: Please post some sample data and some sample results.

Comment: Do you know approximately how many NA values you have? Even with a matirx of 100,000 rows and 1 column both `dist` and `rdist` give an error.

Comment: Basicaly if hay remove all rows with NA I have around 60K of 150K. So there are 90K rows with NAs. However I don't want to calculate all the distances between all the rows, only the distances from a subset of 50 rows with the rest. This is because I use `rdist`.

Comment: From your above comment you might want to look at the `pdist` package and function [pdist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdist/pdist.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @duHaas. `pdist` is nearly what I need, except it don't scale to the number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the answer of @deHaas and his comments I could write an efficient version of `rdist` that handles NAs as `dist`

```
library(pdist)

rdist.w.na <- function(X,Y)
{
  if (!is.matrix(X)) 
    X = as.matrix(X)
  if (!is.matrix(Y)) 
    Y = as.matrix(Y)
  distances <- matrix(pdist(X,Y)@dist, ncol=nrow(X), byrow = TRUE)
  #count NAs
  na.count <- sapply(1:nrow(X),function(i){rowSums(is.na(Y) | is.na(X[i,]))})
  #scaling to number of cols
  distances * sqrt(ncol(X)/(ncol(X) - na.count))
}
```

In particular `rdist.w.na(X,X)` is equivalent to `dist(X)`, but it returns a full symmetric matrix instead a lower triangular one.

Comment: P.S. if you pass `diag=T` and `upper=T` to `dist` you get a full symmetric matrix. Also, your above function seems to work well!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

After looking at this post [dist handling na's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117174/function-dist-not-behaving-as-expected-on-vectors-with-missing-values) I think it looks like there really isn't anyway to get `rdist` to handle NA values. Also, that post looks at how `dist` might compensate for removing missing values.

Using this information I wrote this following script.

```
rdist.alt <- function (x1, x2, na.rm=TRUE) 
    {
    lx <- length(x1)
      if (missing(x2)) 
            x2 <- x1
    if (!as.matrix(x1))
        x1 <- as.matrix(x1)
    if (class(x2) == "matrix")
        x2 <- as.vector(x2)
    if (na.rm)
        na.id <- is.na(x1) | is.na(x2)
        x1 <- x1[!na.id]
        x2 <- x2[!na.id]
        lxa <- length(x1)
    eucd <- sqrt(sum((x1 - x2)^2) * lx/lxa)
    return(eucd)
    }

dist(rbind(vx,vy))
dist(rbind(vx,vy.na))
rdist(vx,vy)
rdist.alt(vx,vy)
rdist.alt(vx,vy.na)
```

all return 8.660254 where as:

```
rdist(vx,vy.na)
Error in rdist(vx, vy.na) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)
```

as `rdist` does not handle missing values.

However, if you are looking to input a matrix and expect output like this from `dist`

```
 dist(xy)
           1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
2  1.9305914                                                            
3  2.2242914 2.8088390                                                  
4  3.1357792 2.1320489 2.1348279                                        
5  1.1663478 1.1691107 2.5429175 0.1244745                              
6  5.0549708 4.1017549 3.4565211 2.0071521 0.1149399                    
7  6.2926407 5.0060108 4.9231242 3.1572273 1.5159374 1.5263946          
8  7.3670783 6.0345762 5.9742805 4.2325789 2.0813721 2.5321716 1.0769671
9  8.0027390 7.1469945 6.1154624 5.0492331 0.8702670 3.0471724 2.6166746 2.3143221 
10 9.0061376 8.1080028 7.1207560 6.0279981 0.6962094 4.0210617 3.3833115 2.8031196 1.0075455
```

You will have to modify the script above. Hope this helps.

---------Original Post-----------------

You can always call `na.omit` on the matrix before passing it to the `rdist` function.

E.g.

```
xy <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), y = c(-1.07436356530045, 0.577054958924021, -2.0477453543004, -0.161614353806037, -0.249631114549562, -0.33090588210086, 0.822298505061525, 1.22212120980467, -0.865002838232734, -0.741925512264102)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

xy2 <- na.omit(xy)
rdist(xy2)
```

Or if you don't care about retaining the NA values

```
xy <- na.omit(xy)
rdist(xy)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way is not like 'dist' handles NAs. From 'dist' help: _"Missing values are allowed, and are excluded from all computations involving the rows within which they occur. Further, when Inf values are involved, all pairs of values are excluded when their contribution to the distance gave NaN or NA. If some columns are excluded in calculating a Euclidean, Manhattan, Canberra or Minkowski distance, the sum is scaled up proportionally to the number of columns used. If all pairs are excluded when calculating a particular distance, the value is NA."_

Comment: I added a sample code of how `dist` handles NAs. It don't omits rows or columns, only single values and scales the result to take into account the total number of columns. In any case, thank you for your interest.

Comment: Okay, totally thought third option worked but it doesn't. I have found some links that should hopefully help. I will update my answer if I can figure this out [NA's in dist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117174/function-dist-not-behaving-as-expected-on-vectors-with-missing-values)

Comment: I think the line `na.id <- is.na(x1) | is.na(x2)` should be `na.id <- t(is.na(x1) | is.na(t(x2)))`. On the other hand this 'only' calculate distance between one vector and one matrix. Nonetheless a useful possibility. Thanks.