# cross product of two matrices with missing values

Tags: r, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I would like to vectorize a distance matrix calculation by using the Law of Cosines. For a matrix with no missing values, this calculation is even faster than `dist` for very big matrices.
The function goes like this:

```
vectorizedDistMat <- function(x,y) {
    an = rowSums(x^2)
    bn = rowSums(y^2)    
    m = nrow(x)
    n = nrow(y)
    tmp = matrix(rep(an, n), nrow=m) 
    tmp = tmp +  matrix(rep(bn, m), nrow=m, byrow=TRUE)
    sqrt( abs(tmp - 2 * tcrossprod(x,y) ))
}
```

Now, missing values complicate things, especially in the last line of the above function, when the two matrices are multiplied. There is a way of accounting for missing values retrospectively, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785475/does-a-function-like-dist-rdist-exist-which-handles-nas). But how do I efficiently prevent missing value to "multiply" when multiplying the matrices?
See for example `M1` and `M2` below:

```
set.seed(42)
M1 = matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
M2 = matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
M1[1,2] = NA
M2[3,4] = NA
```

here, `tcrossprod(M1, M2)` yields NA's in the first row and third column. How do I account for them and get rid of them in advance (like the built-in function `dist`)?